# MailKit - Unexpected behaviour of Dissconnect

Tags: vb.net, mailkit

I use MailKit to send messages, app runs on Win 10.
I wrote my Mailservice, and my project used this service to send infos, warnings or fault notifications to me.

In the case that more messages should be sent within a short periode (loop ?), I get the error 'Too many connections open .."

Ok. I used 'Await' to await the end of each step and so I await the end of the disconnect-operation.
How can I get too many open connections?

````
Private Shared Async Function TransmitMail(mail As MimeMessage) As Task(Of Boolean)
        Try
            Using client = New SmtpClient()
                With client
                    Await .ConnectAsync(Host, 587, False)
                    Await .AuthenticateAsync(UserName, Password)
                    Await .SendAsync(mail)
                    Await .DisconnectAsync(True)
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)    <<<<--
                End With                                 |
            End Using                                    |
            Return True                                  |
```                                                      |
After adding a explicite sleep of about 5 seconds, the problem is gone.

Any explaination?

Thanks for helping.

With best regards

Gerhard
````

Answer (score 0):

Just because you closed and cleaned up the socket on the local machine doesn't mean that the server has had a chance to close and cleanup the socket at the remote end.

Comment: Thats my guess too. I hoped that the underlying protocol will handle that in a good way, but ....